# Matrix with 3 dots does not render to pdf in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I want to show a matrix in `Rmarkdown` pdf file. Using basic `LaTeX` I created my desired matrix representation:

```
$$X_{123} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1} & \dots & a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1} & a_{1}\\
\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots &\ \vdots\\
a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n} & \dots & a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n} & a_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

When I type this matrix in `Rmarkdown` file, the preview window shows my desired matrix:

[image]

However, when I knit the `Rmd` file to pdf I get this error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

When I delete all the `\vdots` and `\dots` which create the 3 dot symbols the rendering works fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a LaTeX problem rather than an RMarkdown problem.  If you delete any column (so the matrix only has 10 columns, not 11) it is fine.

The reason it works in the preview is that RStudio uses MathJax, not LaTeX, for rendering.

Searching online for "10 column limit in matrix in amslatex" finds this link:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/how-to-use-more-than-10-tab-stops-in-bmatrix-or-other-amsmath-matrix-environment, which explains that you can increase the limit by using

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```